# Why does duplicated bean cause StackOverflowError but not any reasonable error message?

Tags: java, spring, infinite-loop

The following code causes `StackOverflowError` error, no any sane message:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

public class DuplicateBeans2 {

   public static class MyClass {
   }


   @Configuration
   public static class Config1 {

      @Bean
      MyClass myClass() {
         return myClass();
      }
   }

   @Configuration
   public static class Config2 {

      @Bean
      MyClass myClass() {
         return myClass();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config1.class, Config2.class);

   }

}
```

Why? Isn't this bad design not to report this explicitly?

**UPDATE**

Sorry people, this is my fault, I just wrote incorrect:

```
      @Bean
      MyClass myClass() {
         return new MyClass();
      }
```

Comment: Could you please still post the stack trace?

Comment: Your recursive calls in `myClass()` will fill up the call stack and make everything stop. This has nothing to do with spring. Try to call this directly from a `public static void main()` method and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the problem here is nothing to do with duplicate beans.  The real problem is that the `myClass()` method is calling itself unconditionally.   You would get the same effect with this class:

```
   public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           main(args);
       }
   }
```

> Why?

You get the problem because `myClass()` calls itself unconditionally ...

> Isn't this bad design not to report this explicitly?

I wouldn't say so.  The Java compiler cannot be expected to warn about all mistakes that the programmer might conceivably make.  I would argue that it is "not worth it" in this case because:

- the mistake is unusual, and
- the result of the mistake is a exception that is easy for a non-novice programmer to diagnose

Then consider this example:

```
  public class A {

      public void test() {
          recurse();
      }

      public void recurse() {
          recurse(); 
      }
  }
```

Now add this:

```
  public class B extends A {
      @Override
      public void recurse() {
          // do nothing
      }
  }
```

If you call `test` on an `A` instance, you will get StackOverflowError.  If you call it on a `B` instance you won't.   If the compiler warned that `A.recurse()` was erroneous, it would be wrong.